# Laplace transform of incomplete Laplace integral

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I am stuck with the following integration which looks like a Laplace transformation of an incomplete laplace integral,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{x+p}f(y)e^{-s\eta y}dy\right)f(x)e^{-s\eta x}dx$$

Any help, regarding how to proceed, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you "clean up" the inside: z=x+p and call the inside integral F(z,s), then substitute x=z-p in the outside you will have a parametrized (p) product: F(z,s)*f(z-p) term to take the Laplace xform z->s of the  product (with a delay term in exp(s*p), absorbing the $\eta$ as a scalar in s).  Of course, the generalized form of the product results in a convolution is the s domain; as usual.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Indeed I got a convolution in the Laplace space. Is it possible to take another Laplace transform of the convolution in the S space to get a multiplication of two functions ?

Comment: How about a clue, :)  For instance, does f(y) have a Taylor expansion or possibly can it be expressed/represented as "Special Function".   In the abstract,  i.e. it has a Laplace xform, I don't think I can carry out the abstract result.  If you don't get an answer here, you might try posting in https://mathoverflow.net/  .   If you get an answer there, you can comment/message me there (or here) @rrogers (I think), I would like to see it.